# Bad translation of value for YAML processor (Jackson, SnakeYAML) in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm trying to read from a YAML properties file in my spring boot application. Here's the content from the file,

```
KEY1:
   KEY2:
     VAL1: 08:00:00
   KEY3:
     VAL2: 16:00:00
```

When I get the value from the YAML processor, The value is translated as 57600 for KEY1.KEY3.VAL2.

Only If I make the value as 09:00:00, Anything lesser than 10:00:00, It's working. KEY1.KEY2.VAL1 gives the proper value Since its lesser than 10:00:00.

Note:
The values here correspond to a particular point in time in a day.

Comment: are you mapping those values to a String, int or Date? Or maybe something else.

Comment: I did a debugging, Seems like the value is mapped to an Integer. I do want this to be String.

Comment: Did you try to put double quotes around the values? It should force the values to be mapped as strings

Comment: This worked. Thanks, @MensurQulami. Can you post this below, So I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put double quotes around values so that they will be forced to be mapped as String. Like so:

```
KEY1:
   KEY2:
     VAL1: "08:00:00"
   KEY3:
     VAL2: "16:00:00"
```